# Smooth affine variety which is not a complete intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is an example of an affine algebraic variety which is smooth but fails to be a complete intersection.

The standard example in projective space is the twisted cubic. So I thought of taking the affine cone of this, except that it fails to be smooth at the origin.

Comment: Can you intersect the cubic with the affine plane ?

Comment: No because you can move the residual line of intersection to infinity.

Comment: Some answers here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27197/local-complete-intersections-which-are-not-complete-intersections.

Comment: Matrix of a given rank gives also an easy example